# Count of rows for every date between a two dates MySQL where no rows

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have a table with no data.
The table has `entry_date` column.
I will provide two dates like `"2017-06-14","2017-06-18"`.
I want to select count of rows exists for each date like

```
    count | entry_date
    ------------
    0     | 2017-06-14
    0     | 2017-06-15
    0     | 2017-06-16
    0     | 2017-06-17
    0     | 2017-06-18
```

*Table may not have entry for particular date,So It should return 0 for that date

Comment: please comment reason before downvoting the question

Comment: You question is unclear. Why can't you just do `18-14`?

Comment: you said table has no data. but you want to count rows. this is not clear to me

Comment: Table may not have entry for that date,So it should return 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in below code.You can create calendar table.Which provide us exact calendar as we required.
Make entry into that calendar table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS time_dimension;

CREATE TABLE time_dimension (
        id                      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  -- year*10000+month*100+day
        db_date                 DATE NOT NULL,
        year                    INTEGER NOT NULL,
        month                   INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 12
        day                     INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 31
        quarter                 INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 4
        week                    INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 52/53
        day_name                VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, -- 'Monday', 'Tuesday'...
        month_name              VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, -- 'January', 'February'...
        holiday_flag            CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'f' CHECK (holiday_flag in ('t', 'f')),
        weekend_flag            CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'f' CHECK (weekday_flag in ('t', 'f')),
        event                   VARCHAR(50),
        UNIQUE td_ymd_idx (year,month,day),
        UNIQUE td_dbdate_idx (db_date)

) Engine=MyISAM;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS fill_date_dimension;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE fill_date_dimension(IN startdate DATE,IN stopdate DATE)
BEGIN
    DECLARE currentdate DATE;
    SET currentdate = startdate;
    WHILE currentdate < stopdate DO
        INSERT INTO time_dimension VALUES (
                        YEAR(currentdate)*10000+MONTH(currentdate)*100 + DAY(currentdate),
                        currentdate,
                        YEAR(currentdate),
                        MONTH(currentdate),
                        DAY(currentdate),
                        QUARTER(currentdate),
                        WEEKOFYEAR(currentdate),
                        DATE_FORMAT(currentdate,'%W'),
                        DATE_FORMAT(currentdate,'%M'),
                        'f',
                        CASE DAYOFWEEK(currentdate) WHEN 1 THEN 't' WHEN 7 then 't' ELSE 'f' END,
                        NULL);
        SET currentdate = ADDDATE(currentdate,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END WHILE;
END
//
DELIMITER ;

TRUNCATE TABLE time_dimension;

CALL fill_date_dimension('2000-01-01','2018-01-01');
```

Once that calendar table is created, you can write below query and it will resolve your issue.

```
SELECT COUNT(datetime) ,DB_DATE FROM time_dimension TD
LEFT JOIN YOUR_TABLENAME TN ON DATE(TN.entry_date)=TD.db_date
WHERE TD.DB_DATE BETWEEN '2017-06-14' AND '2017-06-18'
GROUP BY  DATE(DB_DATE);
```

Hope this will helps.

Comment: Thank you, Exactly what I needed.